# Assign BackSpace to Super_R or Menu button in /etc/default/keyboard

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I am running Debian 9. I bought a new keyboard that I love, but the BackSpace key is very small. I would like to assign BackSpace to the right Super key or Menu key (also on the right lower side).

For my Vim usage, in `/etc/default/keyboard`, I was able to swap the Escape key and Caps Lock key with:
`XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape"`
This works perfect. It works in a console (I believe the two packages `console-common` and `console-data` may be required), in the GUI, and system wide as I'd like. How could I also assign the BackSpace key to Super_R or Menu? Something like the following does not work (after rebooting of course):
`XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape,backspace:nomenu"`

Where could I find a full list of the key names used in the `/etc/default/keyboard` file? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the correct key names by looking at the file, `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`. The key names used in `/etc/default/keyboard` are on the left side in angle brackets, for example:
`key <BKSP> {   [ BackSpace, BackSpace  ]   };`

If you want to change out keys at the graphical level but system wide, you can change it in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`. (Make sure the file corresponds though to `XKBMODEL` in `/etc/default/keyboard`.) Just change out the names you want on the right side. I was thankful for [this article](https://ictsolved.github.io/blog/linux/remap-key-in-linux). If you want to change it at the system level, in X and in the console, you can change the information in `/etc/default/keyboard`. Now my `/etc/default/keyboard` has this line, and I achieved my desired result to assign the BackSpace to my Super_R key.
`XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape,bksp:norwin"`
(The above also includes where I swap Caps_Lock and Escape.)

Update: The above method in changing the `/etc/default/keyboard` file does not seem to work or at best does not have consistent results. However, changing the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file does work. In my experience, sometimes the key assignment in the latter file works in a console and sometimes not.